# I am trying to add an icon to my html title but the icon is not showing

Tags: html

This is the code I tried using

```
<link rel="icon" type="image" href="vt.png">
```

but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: is `vt.png` in the same folder as you html file?

Comment: vt.png is in an image folder

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

The requirements link has been helpful this is the new code

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="img/vt.png">
```

now the title icon is displaying

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that it should be .png not .pg

If you want to support multiple devices and browsers check out :
https://realfavicongenerator.net/

It will tell you the html to use and generate all the files required from an uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to set a favicon to your page you have to note the following:  [requirements](https://sympli.io/blog/2017/02/15/heres-everything-you-need-to-know-about-favicons-in-2017/)